OpenApi Generator generated API messes up TimeZones
I am trying to generate the Frontend and Backend API using the OpenAPI generator. In my schema I have the following object:
Range:
  type: object
  properties:
    creationDate:
      type: string
      format: date
    from:
      type: string
      format: date-time
    to:
      type: string
      format: date-time

For the backend I use following typeMappings in my gradle file to make my Model use LocalDateTime instead of OffsetDateTime:
typeMappings = ['string+date-time': 'LocalDateTime']
importMappings = ['LocalDateTime': 'java.time.LocalDateTime']

Now the generated model for my backend looks like this:
@Valid
private LocalDate creationDate;

@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime from;

@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime to;

The frontend simply uses Date for both types. It is executed simply using:
openapi-generator-cli generate

The problem I am now facing is, that the Dates and Times that I get out of a form in my frontend have timezone information (GMT+2) attached to them. When being passed into the backend, the generated frontend code calls the following method:
'from': value['from'] == null ? undefined : ((value['from']).toISOString()),

This leads to the time being set back by 2 hours since the GM+2 indicates a 2 hour time difference.
However in the backend the date I get is treated with the value it receives (so with 2 hours prior) but as GMT+2. Which means that the value in the backend is actually saved as 2 hours earlier than what has been put in.
The same applies to the date, which in this case leads to the date being saves as a day earlier.
I am at a loss of what I am doing wrong or how I could solve this without manually kicking over the timezone in the data I pass into the generated service.

It's always a good idea to store dates in UTC..
